# Cannot open directory in Linux, but I can absolutely 'ls' to show it up

Tags: linux

I'm using "Web Terminal"

My tree files: /li/modules/

Show path:

```
[cloud_user@f9c89e938e1c modules]$ pwd
/lib/modules
```

Get list:

```
[cloud_user@f9c89e938e1c modules]$ ls
    3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64  3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64  3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64  3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64  3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64
```

The last one `3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64` have already exist.
So, why this command do not work:

```
[cloud_user@f9c89e938e1c modules]$ cd /li/modules/3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64
-bash: cd: /li/modules/3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64: No such file or directory
```

or (same):

```
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/
```

Would you tell me what exactly "No such file or directory" means? Thanks a lot!

Comment: curiously, does `cd "/li/modules/3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64"` work?

Comment: *I'm using "Web Terminal"* - web terminal of what? Be more specific. This does not sound like a programming question, you might be better off asking at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: You need to spend days in reading *books* about Linux. If you are student, your university library has some of them. See also [Linux man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/)

Comment: Is a type that some places you show `/li/`, while your `pwd` output shows `/iib/` ? (note that `/lib/` IS more typical in *nix land, and not `/li/`). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I absolutely need to spend day and day in reading books about Linux first.